# Titanium Development in Sublime Text 2

Tags: titanium, sublimetext2, titanium-mobile, sublimetext

I'm interested in working with Titanium 3.x to develop iOS and Android applications. However, I don't like Eclipse-based IDEs, and don't like the Titanium IDE at all. My love goes to Sublime Text, so I'm wanting to set up a workflow with ST and Titanium.

How can I run my apps straight from Sublime Text?

I'm used to the web development workflow which is very rapid; code, save, test, repeat. Does anyone have any suggest on how to get the same kind of workflow: I want to be able to write code, save it, then test it quickly. Is there a way to make the build process quicker?

Answer (score 3):

and another useful post on the topic: http://www.dunkelgames.com/tutorials/use-sublime-text-to-code-for-appcelerator-titanium-platino

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this guy wanted to do the same thing.  Looks like a good starting point:
http://unbounded.io/post/28394170197/titanium-mobile-develpoment-with-sublime-text-2-and